# How to link two filtered views

Tags: 7, views

I have two related views to display pictures in a gallery. 
The first created view is "**gallery**" which display small pictures using

1. Responsive_grid format
2. Filter on a field category
3. 24 items/page

The second created view "**gallery_details**" use the same filter, only one item by page, and a large picture of the same content type.

I would like to link all pictures from the first view (gallery) to the corresponding one in the second view (gallery_details).

Do I have to create a specific module to do that? I try to find a solution using [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51788/views-how-to-override-a-linked-content-title-fields-href-programmatically?rq=1) but not sure that is the good way to do it.

The idea is that both views will have the same number of results, and each item of the first view result correspond to a page of the second view (because we display 1 item/page). Also it should be possible for example on the third item to add     `<a href="http://www.example.com/?q=gallery_details&page=3"><div> ...</div></a>`
 around it.

To simplify I also use the module `views-fieldsets` to group text fields in a `<div>` that should be the one to link to the gallery_details item/page.

Comment: I did some modification to clarify my question.

Comment: Is gallery_details pulling in information from different content types? It seems that gallery_details would make more sense as content if not.

Comment: @sareed there is only one content with two size of the same picture, and a full description of the picture when you go on gallery_details. While gallery has only the title, dimension and 2 or 3 other things. It is also possible for the user to give a part of the picture instead of the miniature for the gallery display.

Comment: It sounds like 'gallery_details' should be a custom content-type. This would allow you to use 'link to content' from the 'gallery' view. Otherwise you will probably have to rewrite the link field on 'gallery' to pass the argument from one view to the other. Then use contextual filters on 'gallery_details'.

Comment: @sareed, you are right this is a custom content type, but we need to be able to change filtering and to navigate from the previous result to the next one from gallery_details view.

Comment: Ok, so you need a view attached to the gallery_details nodes with contextual filter on nid. I can't think of the 'next' selection off the top of my head. Maybe some custom code to change the offset? I will try this out when I get a few.

Comment: @sareed, oups there is probably a mistake, gallery and gallery_details are views used to display the same content type named content_gallery. Gallery and gallery_details use the same filters.